# Sound Mixer Menu System for DNN

Tags: javascript, css, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I am more of database/programmer type and not great with design.  I am setting up a DotNetNuke website (9.1.1) and would like a menu system that would emulate a sound mixer.  Each of the top level menu items would look like the channel slider of a mixing board, with the name of the section being on the slider button.  Below the slider bar there would be just a bar, showing sub-level links for that section. Above the sliders would be volume lights for each section. If the user is not at that section, the slider would be at halfway, and the lights would go up and down dimly in the mid range. If the user is at that section, the slider would be up to about 75%, the lights would glow brighter, and they would go up and down in a higher range.

I would like this to be responsive, so that the menu can work on mobile devices as well as regular browsers.  If it is possible not to use images, and strictly use HTML and CSS this would be ideal.  If javascript is necessary for the animated effects, so be it.

I am just looking for a place to start on this. I just don't know what's possible in this realm. Of course, if somebody wants to make a few bucks, I would be open to paying a small amount.

Comment: [input type 'range'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) looks pretty simple. Then you could customize it from there. That's what i would do. Straight HTML.

Comment: Are you suggesting the range input for the slider or for the lights, or for both?